# Raspberry Pi Bluetooth LE connection to RedBearLab shield

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am trying to connect to RedBearLab BLE shield from RaspPi. I am using
CSR4.0 USB dongle http://www.adafruit.com/products/1327
Raspberry Pi Rev-B board with Raspbian OS
Bluez-5.11

I have the RedBearLab BLE shield connected to Arduino UNO R3. I am trying to connect to the shield from the RaspPi(attached CSR4.0). But it can't connect - connection attempts time out/resource busy.

Below steps I use

```
$ sudo hcitool lescan

LE Scan ...
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx BLE Shield
$ sudo hcitool lecc xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Could not create connection: Connection timed out

Using gatttool doesn't solve the problem either

```
$ sudo gatttool -b xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx --interactive

[ ][xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx][LE]> **connect**

Attempting to connect to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Error: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)

[xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx][LE]>
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your adapter is busy. Something is using it. Is there any other device connected to your adapter? Try resetting your adapter with:

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
```

Comment: sometimes you need to reset it at the USB level  (which can be done physically by just unplugging the dongle and re-plugging it in).  I've had issues with dongles such that the HCI reset didn't do anything.

Comment: I get `hciconfig: invalid option -- 'i'` using bluez 4.99, but omitting `-i` seems to do the trick :-)

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some BLE devices require a random address at connection time. Try:

```
sudo gatttool -t random -b xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx --interactive
```